Can not compile kotlin project with intelij IDEA becuase of `ConsistentCopyVisibility`
I have a maven + kotlin + spring boot project. project>properties>kotlin.version is 2.0.20. I have data classes with private constrcutors. I add this <arg>-Xconsistent-data-class-copy-visibility</arg> to project>build>pluginManagment>plugins>plugin(kotlin-maven-plugin)>configuration>args.
From the console projects builds and run just fine, but when I want to start my app via IDEA it prints:

Kotlin: Non-public primary constructor is exposed via the generated
'copy()' method of the 'data' class.
The generated 'copy()' will change its visibility in future releases.
To suppress the warning do one of the following:

Annotate the data class with the '@ConsistentCopyVisibility' annotation.
Use the '-Xconsistent-data-class-copy-visibility' compiler flag.
Annotate the data class with the '@ExposedCopyVisibility' annotation    (Discouraged, but can be used to keep binary compatibility).

To learn more, see the documentation of the
'@ConsistentCopyVisibility' and '@ExposedCopyVisibility' annotations.


That is just a warning so unless you are using -Werror it shouldn't block compilation. As for the compiler arg, you can try putting that compiler arg in your pom.xml, I'm going to guess you put it in some global settings that are overwritten by the ones in the pom.

-Werror was set on my project that is why compilation was "blocked".
I reinstall inteijIDEA and it helped
